# Debug flow through express Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, debugging

I've been looking for a way to better trace the code flow through an `express` `Node.js` application.

I've tried the `DEBUG` environment variable but it's not quite what I am looking for.

I am thinking more along the lines of which files were hit as part of the middleware flow, which routers were hit, which files were rendered including filenames/line numbers/function names.

This would be very, very useful.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: For which  routes were hit, that's just a simple middleware placed as your first middleware that always calls next.  If it's static files, you could just have a look at serveStatic middleware and see how you can intercept.  Filenames / line numbers, that one seems a bit odd, how would you expect that to be logged?.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Istanbul (https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul)? It is a code coverage tool. The output is a set of HTML files that shows you how many times **each line** of code was executed. It doesn't exactly show flow but gives you a hint of what got executed.

Comment: There is also a full-fledged debugger available in node - https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html. Scroll to the bottom to see instructions of how to connect a node.js application to Google Chrome's debugger for a GUI interface. You can use the `debugger` keyword in your code to force node to pause at that line then step through your code in the debugger

Comment: @slebetman doesn't help much when you don't know where to put the `debugger` statement, unfortunately.

Comment: @slebetman using `istanbul` is an interesting way of going about it.. a huge pain though.. and like you said you still don't get the flow and you need to infer it.

Comment: For Express you just have an empty top-level first middleware (`app.use()`) that contains only `debugger` then add breakpoints as you go by looking at `req`. You do know that everything in express is just a linear sequence of middlewares don't you? Even the routes are "middlewares" except that they are not in the middle.